# C# Pdf Creation Library from Html strings

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf

All the content I need to show in a pdf is in the database as encoded html.
Is there a c# library that can take html and generate pdf file?

I tried https://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/ but it has the following issues:
Only first 4 pages show, remaining are blank.
The text gets cut off at page break.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using http://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx, which perfectly fit my requirements.

I am using it in an ASP.Net MVC project, 3 lines of code did it.

```
var htmlToPdf = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter();
byte[] pdfBytes = htmlToPdf.GeneratePdf(htmlString);    
return File(pdfBytes, "application/pdf");
```

Its available in nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NReco.PdfGenerator/

Comment: This library works fine when I run it locally on my machine, but on the hosting server, I am seeing the following error randomly. Pdf gets generated sometimes but sometimes it throws the following error.

"Error. An error occurred while processing your request. Cannot generate PDF: (exit code: 1)".